# Pass objects from javascript to Chart.JS through EJS

Tags: node.js, chart.js, ejs

I have an object (data) coming from a js file.

```
router.get('/participant-module',(req,res)=>{

    let sql = dbModel.participant_per_module;
    db.query(sql, (err, result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('dashboard', {title:'Get', data:result});
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

data contains two arrays; emp_id and module_id;

I wanted to pass this variable data to Chart JS data in ejs.

```
  let pchart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type:'bar',
            data:{
              labels: '<%=data.emp_id%>',
                datasets:[{
                    label:'p',
                    data:[123,234,533,232]
                }]
            }
        })
```

But it returns null (i.e. labels = '')

Am I missing something? I have tried different ejs tag like <%- but it returns the same.

Kind regards,
D

Comment: can you share the structure of data? also try this: console.log('<%= data %>') and check the data in browser console

Comment: Hi @Aimsat, console.log does not show anything. This behaves the same as the labels data. 

the structure of the data is

[
  RowDataPacket { emp_id: 4, module_id: 1 },
  RowDataPacket { emp_id: 4, module_id: 2 },
  RowDataPacket { emp_id: 4, module_id: 3 },
  RowDataPacket { emp_id: 4, module_id: 4 }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is an array of objects. You can access the emp_id in following manner using backtick:

```
labels: `<%= data[0].emp_id %>`, `<%= data[1].emp_id %>`, ... , `<%= data[n].emp_id %>`
```

you can also push the emp_ids into another array and then use that array as labels.

```
var Data = JSON.parse(`<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>`);
var labelsData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++){
   labelsData.push(Data[i].emp_id);
}

let pchart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type:'bar',
    data:{
      labels: labelsData,
      datasets:[{
        label:'p',
        data:[123,234,533,232]
      }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi @Aimsat, I see. The code works well. But, it seems not very efficient if I have a lot of data as it has to iterate through for loop to push the data into a new js array. Any view on this?